# N to N to N relation with MYSQL/Doctrine

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Imagine you have got three object types: persons, baskets and fruits.

Each person has got 0 to N baskets and each basket has got 1 to N fruits. The order of baskets and fruits does not matter. Multiple persons may be linked to the same basket, same for baskets and fruits.

Typical querys are:

- Based on a (random) selection of one or more fruits: Which baskets are a subset of these fruitselection. e.g.:

  ```
  Selection: [apple, banana]

  Basket1:   [apple] - matches
  Basket2:   [banana] - matches
  Basket3:   [apple, banana] - matches
  Basket4:   [apple, orange] - does not match
  ```
- Which persons got a basket matched by the query above.

  ```
  Person1:   [Basket1, Basket3, Basket4]
  Person2:   [Basket2]

  Selection: [apple, banana]

  Results:   [Person1, Basket1]
             [Person1, Basket3]
             [Person2, Basket2]
  ```
- List the baskets and fruits for a person

My idea to model this data structure is as follows:

```
TABLE persons
-------------
id
name


TABLE fruits
-------------
id
name


TABLE persons_baskets (N-N)
------------------------------
person_id
basket_id


TABLE baskets_fruits (N-N)
------------------------------
basket_id
fruit_id
```

Atm. the basket id is a random integer to avoid collisions during parallel transactions. The other ids are auto incremented.

Questions:

- Is this a good way to model the data or is an additional table for baskets that holds one column (id) a better way to do this.
- How to implement this in doctrine? The only way i see is to add the baskets entity as a seperate table, because of the unique identifier for each entity that is required in doctrine

Answer (score 3):

An additional table for baskets would be better. In your solution basket_id is a foreign key, but you have no primary key (id_basket or id_pk_basket) to which it relates.
A additional table makes it also much easier to add data to baskets (like a basket-size).